# Rank MySQL results after joining with another table, also filtering them by a condition

Tags: mysql, left-join, rank, leaderboard, cross-join

I found how to rank results, but have yet to find a solution for how to rank them after they've been filtered by a condition. What I need to do is:

1) Sort scores in descending order
2) Join the results with the account table
3) Filter the results by age and gender (from the account table)
4) Rank them
5) Grab the results within a range of ranks (IE: 25-75, but I put 0-10 for simplicity below)

Each solution I've found either doesn't properly rank them, or ranks them and then filters the results. However, this leaves me with ranks like 1, 3, 4, 6, 10, etc when I want 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. or 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, etc.

Here is what I have right now:

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, a.country, score, user_id, duration, rank
FROM (
    SELECT s.*, a.age, a.gender, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM scores s,
        (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    LEFT JOIN accounts a ON 1
    WHERE a.age>=18 && a.age<=35 && a.gender='m'
    ORDER BY score DESC, duration DESC, time ) `selection`
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.id=user_id
WHERE rank >= 0 && rank <= 10 && a.age>=18 && a.age<=35 && a.gender='m'
```

The problem with the above query is that it gives me correct rankings without any gaps, but the scores are completely out of order. IE. 5, 1, 10, 7, 125, 50, etc. IE. They come out in the same order they are in the database, unsorted.

This is what my previous query looked like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, a.country, score, duration, rank
FROM (
    SELECT s.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM scores s,
        (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    ORDER BY score DESC, duration DESC, time ) `selection`
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.id=user_id
WHERE rank >= 0 && rank <= 10 && a.age>=18 && a.age<=35 && a.gender='m'
```

This query gives me properly sorted scores, but with ranks like 3, 5, 8, 9, 11 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Here is some real-world sample data...
For the sake of time, id, username, country, are all omitted because they are irrelevant data and just repeat all the way down the table. The age all the way down is '34' just as the condition shows, the country and username are the same all the way down since this particular user is the only one in the table with the age of 34.

The first query from above with proper rankings, but incorrectly sorted scores (IE. the same order as they were added to the database):

```
  age | score | rank
--------------------
  34  |   5   |  1
  34  |   1   |  2
  34  |  22   |  3
  34  |  13   |  4
  34  |  23   |  5
  34  |  23   |  6
  34  |  34   |  7
  34  |  32   |  8
  34  |  58   |  9
  34  |  76   |  10
```

The second query from above, properly sorted, but ranks still take other users into consideration when ranking, then get excluded in the final result:

```
  age | score | rank
---------------------
  34  |  76   |  3  --- This should have started at 1
  34  |  62   |  4
  34  |  58   |  5
  34  |  42   |  7  --- Notice 6 was skipped
  34  |  34   |  8
  34  |  32   |  9
  34  |  29   |  10
```

What I expect:

```
  age | score | rank
--------------------
  34  |  76   |  1
  34  |  62   |  2
  34  |  58   |  3
  34  |  42   |  4
  34  |  34   |  5
  34  |  32   |  6
  34  |  29   |  7
```

Comment: Can you please include some sample data for the tables, along with your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, thanks for mentioning that. I've added sample data from my server.

Comment: You have multiple tables in there, but you only showed data for one table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks Tim. That is true, but I excluded it on purpose since it's irrelevant to this issue. It's the "age", "username", and "country" columns. All of which are being associated correctly and are just repeated all the way down. IE. 34, Bob, and USA. In other words, all of the data is associated properly, they just aren't sorting correctly. I suppose I'll add it just so nobody gets confused. edit: Actually, it's going to take too much time and really is irrelevant data.

Comment: If I give you a query for your simple 2 column table would that be sufficient, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, it's pretty tricky since I need it to Join data from another table since the condition uses the accounts table, yet it needs to rank based on the scores table. So what I really need is to A) join the results of the scores table with the accounts table B) filter the results by the data in the accounts table IE. age and gender, then C) I need to apply and ranking to those filtered results. It must be in that order or it will give an incorrect result. If you can have a two column example that does that, it would be great. :)

Comment: So you want to assign a rank to the scores based on the scores being sorted in descending order?  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but with the entire query first being filtered by another condition that exists in another table, and is linked through the player's id in the scores/accounts table. In this case age (and gender). I already have a query for sorting and ranking scores in descending order, but also adding a condition and a join simultaneously is really what has me baffled. :)

Comment: Tables have no order. ORDER BY has no meaning in a subquery except for finding the set of rows for a LIMIT. Also, comma binds more loosely than JOINs. Also, OUTER JOIN ON 1 is CROSS JOIN. (In MySQL just JOIN.)

Comment: PS MySQL does not actually support reading and writing the same variable in the same SELECT statement. All these techniques to increment variables per row are unsound. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47516

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following query based on your sample data set:

```
SET @rank = 0;
SET @score = NULL;

SELECT
    age,
    @rank:=CASE WHEN @score = score THEN @rank ELSE @rank + 1 END AS rank,
    @score:=score AS score
FROM scores
ORDER BY rank;
```

The computes the rank of the scores, in terms of the definition for which "rank" is usually used.  If two scores be the same, then they have the same rank.  If you really want the row number, then the above query can be easily modified.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, a.country, score, user_id, duration, rank
FROM (
    SELECT s.*, a.age, a.gender, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM scores s,
        (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    LEFT JOIN accounts a ON 1
    WHERE a.age>=18 && a.age<=35 && a.gender='m'
    ORDER BY score DESC, duration DESC, time ) `selection`
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.id=user_id
WHERE rank >= 0 && rank <= 10 && a.age>=18
```

Comment: Please look at your formatted post before you finish editing. Read the edit help re block format of code. Please do not just dump code, explain why it answers the question.